# Can we get multiple access tokens for single Box User

Tags: box-api

We are using clientId and clientSecret to get the Access Token for Box.Com. Can we get the multiple access tokens using different user login using the same clientId and Secret.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can generate multiple access tokens for the same user. You'll need to send the user through the OAuth flow each time.

Comment: just tried to send the user in oAuth API, however i have not found any oAuth API which will accept User details as input parameter. Please suggest..